# Mouse events in SWT

Tags: java, events, swt, composite, java-canvas

I defined a Node class extends Canvas class and handle the mouse event.

```
public class Node extends Canvas {
String name;

public String getName() { return name; }

public Node(Composite parent, int style, String name) {
    super(parent, style);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.name = name;       
    this.setBackground(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 0, 0, 0));

    this.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseUp(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Mouse up (" + arg0.x + ", " + arg0.y + ") at node " + getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDown(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Mouse down (" + arg0.x + ", " + arg0.y + ") at node " + getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("Double click at node " + getName());

        }
    });
}
```

and then I created a Composite object and add two Node objects:

```
    Node node1 = new Node(this, SWT.NONE, "node 1");
    node1.setBounds(25, 25, 50, 50);

    Node node2 = new Node(this, SWT.NONE, "node 2");
    node2.setBounds(35, 35, 60, 60);
    node2.setBackground(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 75, 75, 75));
```

Note that I chose the position of nodes such that they share some common areas. Using color to differentiate between two nodes, I recognized that `node1` is shown at the top, while `node2` is shown behind. If I apply mouse events in the sharing areas, `node1` handle the events and `node2` doesn't.

`node2` is added to the composite after `node1`, so I expected `node2` will have the privilege, i.e. if I apply mouse events to sharing areas, `node2` should handle the events.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Moreover, you have to dispose colors when you don't need them anymore. The color you create with `new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 75, 75, 75)` isn't disposed anywhere. That's a memory leak. Cache them somewhere or use system-colors.

Comment: I set bounds for each node. As you can see, area of `node1` is the rectangle (25, 25, 50, 50) and area of `node 2` is the rectangle (35, 35, 60, 60). So they share a common area.

Comment: oh, because they share a common area, when I clicked at that area, I just wonder what node will handle the mouse click event. In my case, `node1` handles the event, while I expect `node2` (because I add `node2` after I add `node1` to the composite).

Comment: To be clearer, when I click at the common area, I have the result `Mouse down (35, 36) at node node 1
Mouse up (35, 36) at node node 1`. Why? Because I add node2 after node1, what I want is `Mouse down (35, 36) at node node 2
Mouse up (35, 36) at node node 2`. So how to fix it? That is my question.

Comment: You shouln't ask me why. I am giving a problem and I am just waiting for a solution. The answer for "why do they have to overlap?" I can just answer you that it is the requirement of my project I am working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21563/discussion-between-nguyen-hieu-and-baz)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see that the control that is visible (and above the other) gets the mouse events. I think this behavior is correct and expected. I don't suppose you are asking that even though `node1` is above `node2` and drawn above but still lets `node2` receive all the mouse events. Which might not be possible using standard ways.

If however you are asking about ensuring that `node2` appears above `node1` and thus receives mouse events, you can reverse the creation order, or you can use [`Control#moveAbove(Control)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.html#moveAbove%28org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control%29) like below:

```java
Node node1 = new Node(this, SWT.NONE, "node 1");
node1.setBounds(25, 25, 50, 50);

Node node2 = new Node(this, SWT.NONE, "node 2");
node2.setBounds(35, 35, 60, 60);
node2.setBackground(new Color(Display.getCurrent(), 75, 75, 75));

// Use moveAbove(null) to move node2 above all its siblings
node2.moveAbove(node1);
```

Comment: As an addition: `node2.moveAbove(null);` will move `node2` to the top.

Comment: Yes I have added that already in the comments above... you missed it :). But thanks for highlighting that again...